# clojure equivalent of python defaultdict

Tags: python, clojure, defaultdict

assuming we have some function f that returns a value that can be used as a dict key:

```
d = defaultdict(set)

for x in xs:
    d[f(x)].add(x)
```

The structure will probably look something like this, but I can't figure out how to **a)** provide a default value and **b)** merge with the existing value

```
(defn build-maps [xs]
  (let [inverse-map {}]
    (reduce (fn [im x]
              (let [y (f x)
                    im' (assoc im y x)] ; want to add x to a set
                im')) inverse-map xs)))
```

**update**, the following seems to work

```
(defn build-maps [xs]
  (let [inverse-map {}]
    (reduce (fn [im x]
              (let [y (f x)
                    new-im (assoc im y (set/union (im y) #{x}))]
                new-im)) inverse-map xs)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would write this is:

```
(apply merge-with into
       (for [x xs]
         {(f x) #{x}}))
```

But if you wanted something closer to your reduce-based plan, you could write:

```
(reduce (fn [m x]
          (update m (f x) (fnil conj #{}) x))
        {}, xs)
```

Comment: The reason for the reduce approach is that I am actually updating two dictionaries at the same time